# Stored Procedure Intermittently slow

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm calling this stored procedure in c# using linq to entites, and it usually takes ~1ms to run, but one in every few hundred calls ends up taking 10-60 seconds.  I thought it was a parameter sniffing issue so I'm using the local @_BuyerID to avoid that. I've also tried adding 'option (recompile)' to the end, and optimize for unknown, with no luck.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBuyerAddresses]
    @BuyerID INT
AS

DECLARE @_BuyerID INT
SET @_BuyerID = @BuyerID

SELECT
    Addresses.AddressID
FROM dbo.Buyers 
JOIN dbo.Addresses ON Buyers.BuyerID = Addresses.BuyerID
WHERE Buyers.BuyerID = @_BuyerID
```

I'm not sure where to focus my search now, parameter sniffing seems to be the most common issue for slow stored procedures but none of those solutions seem to be working for me.

Comment: capture plans for fast and slow.

Comment: Can I use management studio to capture plans for stored procedure executions coming in from linq to entites?  Running the sproc from ssms seems to always work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could optimize your statement to avoid unnecessary reads on the Buyers table and eliminate the redundant @_BuyerID.

Here's how I would write the proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBuyerAddresses]
    @BuyerID INT
AS

SELECT AddressID
FROM dbo.Addresses 
WHERE BuyerID = @BuyerID
```

Part 2:

Consider enabling "Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously" on this database. It may be that the Addresses table is changing enough between queries that the statistics are considered out-of-date and are being updated synchronously during the slowly responding query. This setting would help in that situation.

Comment: Good catch, I updated it to avoid the join but the performance issue showed up again after 300 tests.

Comment: So my first guess it that another process is updating Adresses and blocking your query. Do you have a non-clustered index on Addresses.BuyerID?

Comment: Use SSMS' Activity Monitor while the issue is occurring to help isolate the cause. If it's blocking, it should be fairly obvious as you would see another process listed that involves the same table. Right click near the top of Activity Monitor and change the refresh rate to every 5 seconds or less.

Comment: There is a non-clustered index on BuyerID.  I'm having trouble narrowing down the activity monitor to find relevant info, thanks for this tip though i'm going to start researching in this area

Comment: @MitchWheat If you're implying that the optimizer would remove the join to Buyers in the OP's original query, you'd be wrong.